# Updating or keeping migrations when sync local project with VPS

Tags: django, migration, vps

I'v got django project on local machine and on VPS. The question is when I update the files shall I replace migrations on VPS with those I had on my local machine or update files but leave VPS migrations as they were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to keep identical workflows on local and on production (VPS for example).
This could be done with the help of [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [git](https://git-scm.com/).

Now back to your question, you need from "beginning" to keep exactly synced local and prod.
So yes, you need to have the same migration files both on local and prod, this ensures that you will be having the same database structure.